# Replace url twice and redirect using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want to replace URL with regx as following by using .htaccess.

```
var url = REQUEST_URL
url.replace(regx1, replaced1)
url.replace(regx2, replaced2)
redirect(url, 302)
```

Below code does not change url

```
RewriteRule regx1 replaced1
RewriteRule regx2 replaced2
```

Below code redirects twice, but I want to redirect once.

```
RewriteRule regx1 replaced1 [R=302]
RewriteRule regx2 replaced2 [R=302]
```

Is there a way to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `R` flag from first rule and have it like this:

```
RewriteRule regx1 replaced1 [NC]
RewriteRule regx2 replaced2 [R=302,NC,L,NE]
```

Comment: thank you for answer, but if url matches only first regex, redirection not working